# How can I prevent extraneous backslashes processing JSON in Logic Apps

Tags: json, stored-procedures, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, backslash

I have a Logic App that queries Graph APIs and passes JSON data to a SQL Server stored procedure; this was working fine. But then I found some executions were taking too long (~10 mins) so I changed to invoke the stored procedure via Data Factory, which I've also used successfully. But I now find that the JSON (from Graph) that I could previously send direct to a stored procedure now fails when passed via Data Factory; this fails on incorrectly formatted JSON, apparently due to extraneous backslashes . What's the best way to prevent this?

So the data, as shown in the Output from the API, is fine i.e. is valid JSON, but as presented to ADF, is not; here's a sample of what it looks like i.e. every? " is preceded by a \ and many instances of three consecutive \ characters:

```
"body": "{\"Function\":\"WriteEmail\",\"JSON\":[{\"@odata.etag\":\"W/\\\"CQAAABYAAADbZSEkAs6aQq8r/Vd5TMJeAAFea6nN\\\"\",\"id\":\"AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0A22UhJALOmkKvK-1XeUzCXgABX14cVwAA\",\"createdDateTime\":\"2023-03-27T08:16:23Z\",\"lastModifiedDateTime\":\"2023-03-27T08:17:06Z\",\"changeKey\":\"CQAAABYA
```

The reference to the output looks like:

```
concat('{', '"Function":"WriteEmail",', '"JSON":', body('Get_User_Email')?['value'], ...
```

I can't wrap the "body" reference in a json function, as it is an array ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share format of your api response

Comment: See amended question, above

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace action in logic app expressions and remove extra back slashes. Created logic app and removed back slashes. Below are the steps I followed,

- Created logic app with an Http trigger.
- Next initialized a string variable and passed you response as value as shown below,
  [image]
- Added compose action to remove back slash from the above variable using expression **replace(variables('resp'),'\','')**.
  [image]
- Ran logic app and it removed back slashes from passed string variable,
  [image]

Output of Compose action:

```
"body": "{"Function":"WriteEmail","JSON":[{"@odata.etag":"W/"CQAAABYAAADbZSEkAs6aQq8r/Vd5TMJeAAFea6nN"","id":"AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0A22UhJALOmkKvK-1XeUzCXgABX14cVwAA","createdDateTime":"2023-03-27T08:16:23Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2023-03-27T08:17:06Z","changeKey":"CQAAABYA
```

- Based on details provided, I have implemented this logic. You can change actions as per you requirement and use replace function.

Comment: Yes, I can use Replace to remove characters, but I'm more interested to know why this happens; Logic Apps seems to apply these backslashes itself; how can I stop that happening?

Comment: @JohnD The reason is backslashes are added to JSON in Logic Apps is due to the way that JSON strings are escaped. When a JSON string contains special characters such as quotes or backslashes, they need to be escaped with a backslash. If the JSON string is already escaped, Logic Apps may add additional backslashes, resulting in extraneous backslashes. To prevent this from happening, one option is using "Parse JSON" action in Logic Apps to parse the JSON string and remove the extraneous backslashes. Other option is using "Replace" function to remove the backslashes before parsing the JSON.

Comment: Yeah, that's good, but I think my problem comes from having to use the output (from the HTTP or ParseJSON) as the input to the next step, which is to call Azure Data Factory; this requires a parameter list, built using the concat function, which seems to re-introduce the backslashes I was trying to remove!